# How to find out the index of every element of array after expanding in KUSTO

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have an array in a row that has a start datetime belonging to the first element of the array and an interval which shows the interval between every element in the array in milliseconds.
I need to expand the array and have the calculated datetime for every element after it.

[Example of rows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLwDt.png)

[Desired:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srVrw.png)

Refrain from constant elements. it should be variant in real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`mv-apply` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator), with the `ItemIndex` option.

for example:

```
datatable(pin_serial_id:long, date_time:datetime, roll:dynamic, interval:long)
[
    22021403, datetime(2023-07-26 17:02:59.3820), dynamic([3.54, 3.54, 3.54, 3.54, 3.54]), 100, 
    22021403, datetime(2023-07-26 17:03:00.3820), dynamic([3.54, 3.54, 3.54, 3.54, 3.54]), 100, 
]
| mv-apply with_itemindex = i roll on (
    extend date_time = date_time + interval * 1ms * i
)
| project-away i, interval
```

| pin_serial_id | date_time | roll |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:02:59.3820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:02:59.4820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:02:59.5820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:02:59.6820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:02:59.7820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:03:00.3820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:03:00.4820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:03:00.5820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:03:00.6820000 | 3.54 |
| 22021403 | 2023-07-26 17:03:00.7820000 | 3.54 |

Comment: Thanks. What if we have a changing interval, such as 10, 100, or 120 milliseconds, and we want to get just elements with specific indexes to achieve the desired interval between rows?

For example, we have a 100-element array with an interval of 100 milliseconds. To achieve a desired interval of 1000 milliseconds (for rows), we need to get elements by steps of 1000/100 = 10.

For a 10-millisecond interval, we should get all the elements of the array.

In other words, is there any way to change the step in the query "i" to something like (2i + 1)/2 for elements with odd indexes?

Comment: instead of piggybacking on a previous question with a verbal description of your new question - i'd recommend you start a new question, with a clearer description including a tabular example of the problem you're trying to solve